How to prove that the area bounded by the curve: $x^4+y^4+2 x^2 y^2 -m x^2-(1-m) y^2=0$ is a fixed value? (when 0＜m＜1)
I tried using polar coordinate definite integral, it's easy enough, but is there any easier or more interesting method to prove that?

The origin of this problem: 

Through a point inside the circle, draw two lines AB and CD such that the product of their slopes is a constant. These lines intersect the circle at points A, B, C, and D. Find the trajectory of the midpoint of AC. 
(I also want ask for this problem.)

Consider the circle with equation $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ and a point at (0, 0). This leads to the equation $x^4 + y^4 + 2x^2y^2 - mx^2 - (1 - m)y^2 = 0$. 

However, determining the analytical expression for the trajectory when the point is not at $(0, 0)$ seems to be more challenging.




Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Very confusing. According to the picture the point inside the circle is $A$ and the two lines through it are $AB$ and $AC,.$ They surely do not intersect the circle at points $A$ and $D,.$ What you plotted is surely not the trajectory of the midpoint of $AC,.$ What a mess.

Ahh, the points in the image don't match up with the problem, sorry it's my fault  But the trajectory is correct. I've corrected the points in the image and drawn some new graphs, and the post has been updated.
Thank you so much @Kurt

Can you clarify, what the question is? Are you trying to find an equation for the curve traced by the midpoint of $AC$ when the lines are centered around some other point of the circle?

My question is how to prove that the area bounded by the curve: $x^(4)+y^(4)+2 x^(2) y^(2)-m x^(2)-(1-m) y^(2)=0$  is a fixed value.
I know one way using polar coordinate definite integral, but I am seeking more approaches.
I also want to tackle the original problem, as this one is just a special case of it and the original problem is more interesting and challenging. It requires finding the analytical formula for a curve. I suspect that the curve's enclosed area is constant when point T is fixed, but I have not yet given it a thorough think. @K.Grammatikos

Here's a method that uses polar coordinates but uses a perhaps nonobvious symmetry of the curve. Substituting $x = r \cos \theta, y = r \sin \theta$ gives that the polar coordinate formula for the curve is
$$r^2 = \sin^2 \theta + m \cos 2 \theta ,$$
so the infinitesimal area inside the curve subtended by an infinitesimal angle $d\theta$ at an angle $\theta$ is
$$\frac12 r(\theta)^2 d\theta = \frac12 \left(\sin^2 \theta + m \cos 2 \theta\right) d\theta .$$ But the area subtended by $d\theta$ an quarter-turn away, at $\theta + \frac\pi 2$, is
$$\frac12 r\left(\theta + \frac\pi2\right)^2 \,d\theta = \frac12 \left(\cos^2 \theta - m \cos 2 \theta\right) \,d\theta,$$ and so their combined contribution is just $d\theta$, which is independent of $m$. Using the geometric description of the curve it should be possible to find a coordinate-free interpretation of this statement.
Figure. The computation implies that the blue area of the windmill shape inside the curve is independent of the angle of inclination (and also the angles of the sectors, i.e., the "blades" of the windmill). Plotted is $m = \frac18$.


thank you so much!!!
